# Optimizer Options for tidysynth

Tags: r, statistics, causality

Under the `generate_weights()` command using the {tidysynth} package for executing the synthetic control method in R, users are given a number of optimization options. However, I cannot find documentation on what these optimization options do as {tidysynth} is no longer supported on CRAN (if anyone knows why, I would also like to know that as well).

You can still access reference material for {tidysynth} on GitHub and it has the following code as an example of their optimization options:

```
generate_weights(optimization_window = 1935:1949,
                   margin_ipop = .02, sigf_ipop = 7, bound_ipop = 6)
```

Barring the `optimization_window` option, I am unsure of what the other options are doing and I cannot find documentation discussing these options. What I can find with [avaliable resources](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidysynth/versions/0.1.0/topics/generate_weights) refers to the documentation of `ipop` but such documentation is not provided.